# Is there a phrase/idiom that refers to the irony of putting off a task or goal when it's easiest to achieve?

Tags: expressions, idioms

Or one that refers to taking an opportunity for granted when it is right there in front of you?

Comment: What have you found so far? Why is procrastinate not appropriate? Where will you use this in a sentence?

Comment: Never do today what you can put off until tomorrow.

Comment: Well, that's not *ironic*, just stupid or unfortunate.  That said, I agree with Damila's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a turn of phrase, you could negate a phrase that means doing the task when it is the easiest or most likely to succeed.

**He *didn't* make hay while the sun was shining.** or **He *didn't* strike while the iron was hot.**

Original phrases:

> Make the most of one's opportunities while you have the chance. [Make hay while the sun shines]
>
> To strike while the iron is hot is to act decisively and take an
>   opportunity when it arises.

Both definitions from https://www.phrases.org.uk/